# Getiing error on Apple LLVM Compiler 3 but no error on 4.1

Tags: ios5, ios6, xcode4.2, xcode4.5, llvm

i created a project on xcode 4.5 with LLVM 4.1, but when i sent it to my friend he gets a lot of errors like declare method errors and other errors, but my project works perfectly om my macbook, of course any resources and frameworks doesn't lost.
i wanna know, is there any way to install LLVM 3.0 compiler on xcode 4.5, because my friend cant update his xcode for update size.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to identify what errors you are seeing, so that the project could be made backwards compatible with the version of Xcode your friend is running. LLVM 3.0 wasn't that long ago (Xcode 4.2), so it should support the most significant recent additions of ARC and Storyboards just fine. Are you sure these errors aren't just due to referencing elements of the iOS 6.0 SDK?

Comment: Yes, i've tried it on xcode 4.5, iOS 6.0 with no error.

Comment: Right, that's not what I was asking. We know building it against the latest version of the SDK works, but what exactly is throwing errors on Xcode 4.2? Identifying and fixing those issues will be far easier than trying to address this via compiler transplants.